# How to draw a circular jigsaw piece with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've seen how to use tikz to create a circular jigsaw puzzle with curved pieces. I'm looking for a circle split into two jigsaw pieces, one with a protruding edge and the other with an internal edge. I tried using the 'rounded corners' attribute but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `jigsaw` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{jigsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (1.05,0.5) circle [radius=0.48cm];
  \piece[blue]{0}{-1}{0}{1}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \piece[red]{0}{-1}{0}{1}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]